# MOSFET to connect two batteries in series

Tags: batteries, mosfet, fet

I am designing a small bidirectional circuit consisting of two batteries in series as a power source. Part of the circuit will be a charger, to charge the batteries when they are not in use, which is triggered by external circuitry.

The problem I am having is that each battery has its own charging circuit, therefore I think that the must be disconnected from each other in order to facilitate charging.

I had the idea of using a MOSFET which joins the positive of one battery to the negative of the other battery when the circuit is discharging, and then disconnect the two when it is charging. But I am having difficulty implementing this. I have tried simple simulation with PSPICE using only voltage sources however I could not get it to work. Is this possible? If so how can I do it?

Comment: Please post the schematic you have simulated.

Comment: What MOSFET do you use? How do you drive it?

Comment: If the two chargers are isolated from each other, you shouldn't need to disconnect the batteries from each other. I have done this with two 12V off-the-shelf chargers to charge automotive batteries in series.

Comment: Even if you used a MOSFET to break the series connection, your two battery chargers need to be electrically isolated. That is, they cannot share a common ground.

Usually, it is just easier to design a charger that can charge the two in series. This can have the advantage of allowing both charging and use of the system at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

While thinking that could be used relays the desired operation, I provided an outline of a possible circuit using MOSFETs. Be especially careful that the control signals must be complementary. The intrinsic diode of M1 does not impose a problem for charger 2, since M3 is conducting in this case. I leave to you the determination of resistors and proper part-numbers.

[image: Series battery -connect/disconnect]